# Explicit description of the canonical $\pi_G: \mathrm{Sh}(G_0)\to B_S(\mathbf{G})$

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, locales, internal-groupoids

Given a localic groupoid $\mathbf{G} = (G_1\overset{d_0}{\underset{d_1}{\rightrightarrows}}G_0)$ and letting $B\mathbf{G}$ denote its classifying topos, I'm looking for a explicit description of the direct image of the canonical geometrical morphism $\pi_G: \operatorname{Sh}(G_0)\to B\mathbf{G}$, whose inverse image is the forgetful  functor. Also, Marta Bunge mentions, in *"[An  application of descent to a classification theorem  for toposes](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100068365)"*, that this morphism is essential, that is, the forgetful $\pi_G^*$ has a left adjoint, which I'm also interested in an explicit description of.

Comment: I believe $\pi_*(X)$ is $X^{\Gamma(d_1)}$ with the (right) action of $G_1$ through its (left) action on $\Gamma(d_1)$. Here $\Gamma(d_1)$ is the sheaf of sections of $d_1:G_1\to G_0$. While, $\pi^*(X)$ is most likely $X\times\Gamma(d_0)$ with the (right) action of $G_1$ through its (right) action on $\Gamma(d_0)$